# Open web browser when starting console application debug in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, console, browser

I work on a web server that runs as a console application. It is based on HttpListener. When I start the project in Visual Studio 2012 it opens console.

In addition to starting the console I need to open a web browser.

I know that there is a possibility to start multiple projects in VS. However my requirement is to keep this application as a single project (this is a sample VS project provided with a product SDK, it should be simple).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581

Comment: @volody How does that helps?

Comment: It shows how to run browser in separate thread. Are you looking for solution on how to run webbrowser in second process?

Comment: When I Run my project in VS it should: 1) Run my console app; 2) Open web browser as a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

In your process, after you've started your listener, simply `Process.Start("http://localhost:12345")`; this will start the default web browser at the same time as the application.

You can make this optional based on a command-line switch or other configuration setting.